# Accessing injected dependencies in Guice

Tags: java, singleton, guice

Given a class that has a dependency injected in it using the Guice @Inject annotation, what are the possible options to get a reference to this dependency from outside the class in which it was injected?

Let's say I have the following class A :

```
public class A {

       @Inject 
       private B b;

  }
```

Let's say I want to test class A. I write a JUnit test case :

```
public class TestA {
        @Inject
        private A a;

   }
```

I want to set up some properties of the instance of B in instance of A in my test case before I start testing the methods of class A.

In my test case, what are my options in terms of getting a reference to the instance of class B that has been injected in class A?

I could add a getter in class A to get a reference to the injected instance of B and call this getter in my test case. Although, if class A has 5 more dependencies injected in it, I will have to write 5 getters in A for each dependency.

Another option is to annotate class B with @Singleton so that Guice always gives me the same instance of B no matter where I access it. Although, asking Guice to treat B as singleton just because I want access to it in my test case does not feel right. I might have some state in class B that I don't want to share across all instances of B.

Is there a better option than the ones listed above to get a reference to the injected instance of B in A?

**Edit**
Note that I don't have control over the instantiation of A. We have a class in our in house framework that is going to instantiate A.

Answer (score 2):

The most common and recommended way of *unit* testing `A` would be to avoid using Guice at all in your test.  Create `A` with a reference to `B` that you provide.

```
public class A {

    private final B b;

    @Inject
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

In your test code, just create the `B` (whether it be an actual `B` or a mock) and then create `A` yourself;

```
B b = mock(B.class);
A testUnit = new A(b);
//now you obviously know what b is
```

If you do want to introduce Guice into your testing, you could use a different module configuration where you control how `B` is instantiated.  Since the test will provide the module and the instance of `B`, it should be trivial to obtain the instance of `B` in the test.

Comment: I am new to Guice and working on an existing code base. Some other class in our in-house framework is going to instantiate A. If I understand correctly, the framework class will have to pass an instance of B to A while creating A. I don't think the framework class can be modified to do that. With this limitation in mind, I am forced to inject B at field level. Also, would adding a separate module configuration help considering I don't have control over the instantiation of A in my app? I have edited my question with this info.

Comment: @bot: So Guice isn't creating `A`?  How is `B` getting injected, through `requestInjection()`?  If you're stuck with field-level injection there are still clean ways of breaking those dependencies and allowing you to provide your own mocks.  Mockito has `@InjectMocks`, for example.

Comment: Being new to Guice and the codebase itself, I will need to investigate more on how objects are being wired. I see field level injections in all the classes of this type in the code base. Let's say I don't want to mock B in my test but use the B that would be used in the actual execution of the app. Is there a cleaner way to get a reference to B without mocking if I am stuck with field level injections?

Comment: @bot: Well, you could expose `b` using a package-private `getB()` getter (provided your test is in the same package) or by using Reflection.  Neither options are specific to Guice though.

Comment: Adding getters is an option as already stated in my question. Although, if class A has 5 more dependencies injected in it, I will have to write 5 getters in A for each dependency. I am looking for a cleaner way to do this and I don't want to mock the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to testing DI, check out the [needle4j](http://www.needle4j.org/) framework (formerly needle). It provides a JUnit Rule that "simulates" dependency injection by providing mock instances by default but also lets you configure explicit behavior via annotations.

You then write DI-unit tests like

```
public class ATest {

@Rule
public final NeedleRule needle = NeedleBuilders.needleMockitoRule().build();

@ObjectUnderTest
private A a;

@Inject
private B b;

@Test
public void injects_mock_of_b() {
    // when(b.XXX()).thenReturn(...)
    // assertThat(a.XXX()) ...
}
}
```